Smoothing out data
I have a an array of 2d coordinates where each coordinate is some float.
For the rest of my project, I need a binarised image of 1s and zeros.
Essentially I need the 1s to be where the coordinates are and the 0s elsewhere
If i just construct a 2d matrix and place 1s using a round() function or something, I don't get a sufficiently smooth curve.
I am a newbie to computer vision
Are there any resources/topics I should go and read about to address this problem? Where do I start?

Hello and welcome to Signal Processing SE. Your question could benefit from some plot that could demonstrate the problem. If you have an image, or an approximation (possibly some reference image from a similar solved problem) that shows the expected result (at least qualitatively) would be good to include.

You first say that you have a set of points, but later expect a smooth curve. This means there’s information missing. It would be good if you could better describe your problem. Are the points along the curve? Are they in order? Do you not have sufficiently small distance between these samples to record the smooth curve? Do you need to interpolate?

Could you share the data and some code to visualize what you get?

Sounds like you are looking for a decent plotting algorithm. Without additional knowledge I would point you to Bresenham's algorithm to understand why your plot probably looks jagged and not sufficiently smooth.
Further, I agree with @ZaellixA - An example image (and array) would be helpful.

Since you want to binarise the values, I really can’t see how you would end up with something smooth. What you describe is exactly: going from a smooth representation to a “non-smooth” representation. I think you should clarify what your problem is exactly (or even think about it again as you may seem to have an incomplete idea of what you are trying to achieve here).
